# Cooking and Morale Bonus

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, food-and-drink

One of my players took craft cooking,craft spices and knowledge nature to be able to cook delicious food in the wilderness. Does he get any morale bonuses for eating delicious food everyday?

Comment: Are you looking for what the basic rules say, official rules that make this happen, or something else?

Comment: Official rules if they exist.